# Update indexPath value after deleting a row

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a list of favorite movies. In the table cell, there is a button to delete the movie from the favorites list. So I want to animate it with tableView.deleteRows. But if I delete a row from the top of the screen the other rows coming upward. It is normal but when I was deleting the row from the top of the screen other cells that already shown in the list are not updating indexPath. I assign an asyncAfter method for tableView.reloadData to solve the problem but I think that can cause a crash on the OS side. Because I forced to main thread reload data after a delay. Is it really a problem for OS and what should I do?

**Example problem:**

If I delete the movie which has the 0 index all of the movies coming upward. So before deletion, 1 index movie should has 0 index but it not. If I tried to delete a new 0 index movie it is deleting another movie.

[Work example without tableView.reloadData()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMWg.gif)

Here is my code // This is working but I think asyncAfter is a problem

```
cell.deleteButtonActionBlock = {
    FavouritesHandler.shared.deleteMovie(movie)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you removing the item from the datasource array before `tableView.deleteRows`?

Comment: @Jithin yes FavouritesHandler.shared.deleteMovie(movie) removing movie from array

Comment: I guess there is something wrong how you *capture* the index path.

Comment: @vadian this snippet in tableView cellForRowAt indexPath I don't think so

Comment: I do, that's exactly the issue. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not** use the captured index path if cells can be deleted, inserted or moved.

In the custom cell declare the closure

```
var deleteButtonActionBlock : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
```

and call it

```
deleteButtonActionBlock?(self)
```

In `cellForRow` get the actual index path for the cell

```
cell.deleteButtonActionBlock = { aCell in
    let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)!
    FavouritesHandler.shared.deleteMovie(movie)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [actualIndexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

No (ugly) delay and no (pointless) reloading needed.

Please note also that I removed the `self` in the `delete` line because the tableView instance is available as method parameter.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you please explain why the captured indexPath not working properly? This is my second week in Swift :)

Comment: Yes, the term *capture* contains the explanation. At the moment you assign the closure the index path is frozen and doesn’t change anymore. This causes the unexpected behavior.

Comment: If I don't get it wrong, with using cellForRowAt indexPath updating when cell apers. But with using closure I passed it while I am using deleteButton. I really appreciate You. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `cellForRow` is not being called again after `delete-/insertRows`